# Disable Multiple Desktops Reordering Feature?

Tags: osx-mavericks

I have a new MBP with 10.9 installed on it.  I normally work by swapping between desktops that have a specific function (like one has Mail.app and Cal.app running on it).  Once I started using mavericks I noticed that when I'd click on a dock icon, the order of the desktops is rearranged.  I do not think this is how things worked on 10.7, but as I no longer have that machine, I can't confirm.

Is there a way to disable this behavior because it's very annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if this works for you.

1. Launch `System Preferences` and click on `Mission Control`.
2. Uncheck the box next to `Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use`.
3. Close out *System Preferences*.

With the automatic rearrangement disabled, Mission Control will again remember your app and desktops placement and not reorder them on it’s own.

[image]

<sub>[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/12/stop-spaces-rearranging-mac-os-x/)</sub>